# Prove that $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod 6$. Deduce that $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod {30}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod 6$. Deduce that $7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod {30}$.

So far I know that $z=5k+1$, and $y=6k+1$, for some $y,z \in Z$. In order to show that both of these are equivalent to $7^{100}$, I think I need to put $7^{100}$ in mod form, but I am unsure how to do that. I think the Chinese Remainder Theorem can be applied to solve this, but I don't know how to use this theorem in this context.

Comment: What do you know about fermats little theorem. Look this up.

Comment: Title and text disagree in the last modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that: $$7^2\equiv -1\mod 5 \textrm{ and }7\equiv 1\mod 6.$$
Therefore, one has: $$7^{100}=(7^{2})^{50}\equiv (-1)^{50}\equiv 1\mod 5,$$
$$7^{100}\equiv 1\mod 6.$$
Besides, one has $5\wedge 6=1$ and by chinese remainder theorem: $$7^{100}\equiv 1\mod 30.$$

Answer (score 1):

First use *Little Fermat*: $7$ has order a divisor of $\varphi(5)=4$ modulo $5$, whence the first congruence.   Still simpler, $7\equiv 1\mod 6$, whence the second congruence.

Now calculate  a *Bézout's relation* for $5$ and $6$: $6-5=1$. The  inverse isomorphism in the *Chinese Remainder theorem* is:
\begin{align*}\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/6\mathbf ,\\
(x\bmod5,y\bmod6)&\longmapsto6x-5y\bmod30. \end{align*}
In the present situation, you get
$$7^{100}\equiv 1\mod30.$$

*Note:*  The calculations are not really necessary in the specific case, but the O.P. asked for explaining how the Chinese Remainder theorem works  for this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using binary exponentiation to evaluate $a^n$ (mod n) as follows:

1. Compute the binary representation of n:

   n = $b_02^k + b_12^{k-1} + ... + b_{k-1}2 + b_k$

    where $b_0 = 1$, $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$ for $1\leq i \leq k$ and $k = \lfloor{log_2n}\rfloor$
2. Initialize $r_0 \equiv a$ (mod m)
3. For $0 \leq i \leq k-1$ compute:

   if $b_{i+1} = 0$: $r_i^2$ (mod m)

   if $b_{i+1} = 1$: $r_i^2a$ (mod m)
4. Output $r_k$

This is a pretty simple way you could use to do a direct proof.